# Jasmine 2.0 done and afterEach

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, asynchronous, jasmine

I am using [jasmine 2.0](http://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html).

I am trying to understand the `done()` function.

With the following basic jasmine code:

```
describe('Jasmine 2.0 done()', function() {

    beforeEach(function () {
        console.log('install');
        jasmine.clock().install();
    });

    afterEach(function () {
        console.log('uninstall');
        jasmine.clock().uninstall();
    });


    it('should wait 1ms then complete', function (done) {

        setTimeout(function(){
            console.log('async');
            expect(true).toBe(true);
            done();      
        }, 1)

    });

});
```

What I think I see happen:

- `beforeEach` runs, installing the clock, logs "install"
- The test runs, the setTimeout **does not** do anything
- The test waits for 5 seconds (the default timeout jasmine has before failing)
- The test fails because `done()` is never called.
- I know this because I get the error: `Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.`
- `afterEach` then runs anyway, uninstalls the clock and logs "uninstall"

I would **expect** that

- `beforeEach` runs, installing the clock and logs "install"
- The test runs, waits for one millisecond, runs the log, the expect and `done()`
- `afterEach` runs, uninstalls the clock and logs "uninstall"
- The test passes with no error

I think this because the documentation says

> And this spec will not complete until its done is called.

So I assumed `afterEach` would wait until `done()` is called to execute.

I have tried adding `done()` in the `afterEach` too

```
afterEach(function (done) {
    console.log('uninstall');
    jasmine.clock().uninstall();
    done();
});
```

This made no difference.

Why does this test not succeed?

What am I not understanding about the `done()` function?

[plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/5F9DMkNYjEQoxuduPlQt?p=preview) to show the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When jasmine's mock clock is installed `setTimeout` behavior is overridden. Calls to any registered callback are triggered when the clock is ticked forward via the `jasmine.clock().tick` function, which takes a number of milliseconds ([link to jasmine docs](http://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html#section-Mocking_the_JavaScript_Timeout_Functions))

> Calls to any registered callback are triggered when the clock is ticked forward via the jasmine.clock().tick function, which takes a number of milliseconds.

In your case test spec would look like this:

```
describe('Jasmine 2.0 done()', function() {

    beforeEach(function () {
        console.log('install');
        jasmine.clock().install();
    });

    afterEach(function () {
        console.log('uninstall');
        jasmine.clock().uninstall();
    });


    it('should wait 1ms then complete', function (done) {

        setTimeout(function(){
            console.log('async');
            expect(true).toBe(true);
            done();      
        }, 1);

        jasmine.clock().tick(1);
    });

});
```

Comment: Ah, interesting. I must have missed that. Thank you.
Does the clock also have other effects on asynchronous actions? I.e promises (Which is where this original problem came from)

Comment: Based on jasmine documentation installing mock clock affects only `setInterval` and `setTimeout` functions and shouldn't affect any other native objects. It shouldn't affect native promises, but it could mess up custom promise implementations and polyfills or any other code that uses `setTimeout` and `setInterval`.

Comment: I see. Thanks for your answer. I will use this to try fix my test using promises and let you know if it seems to have an effect.

Answer (score 0):

With Jasmine asynchronous testing, we have to call the async code in the `beforeEach()` and `afterEach()` function that runs before each `it()` function block within a `describe()` function block.

This means that the `done()` callback has to be called within the above mentioned methods, else the test will become synchronous and it blocks the calling thread if it exceeds the timeout interval.

```
beforeEach(function (done) {
    console.log('install');
    jasmine.clock().install();
    done(); 
});

afterEach(function (done) {
    console.log('uninstall');
    jasmine.clock().uninstall();
    done(); 
});
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/h94ubg56/) is a working JSFiddle.

Comment: In your JSFiddle, I don't see the `setTimeout`'s function ever being called? I don't see it log "async"

Comment: I forgot to add `jasmine.clock().tick(1);` in my code, but it's good you managed to get an answer.